# angular promise after render all the data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, http, bigdata

I have a big data that call from `angular` page by `ajax`.

I want to know when the browser finished get the object

my code

```
$http({})
.success(function(data){
deferred.resolve(data);
log("get data");
})
.finally(function(data){
log("finally get data");
});
```

My problem is when I call the `log` function this seems to happend when the browser start ping with the server and not after complete get the object from the server.

Of course the object is big data and take many time, and I Want to know how can I find the second that the object complete get to client

Comment: It's difficult to know for sure, but is your back end code using an async function to retrieve the data, and is returning the request before that async has completed? You may need to post at least your controller/handler function. There's nothing in this code snippet which would cause this behaviour, assuming the http options have been omitted intentionally.

Comment: Are both log messages being printed out? Can you verify that the call to the server is actually happening and returning a successful response?

Comment: Is 'get data' being logged? This looks like a problem with your server. Could you post the code for your controller?
On another note, take a look at [this post](http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/25/dont-use-$https-success/).  It explains why it's best to steer away from Angular's `.success()` function, which is basically just a wrapper for the `.then()` function used on regular promises.

Try something like this:


`$http({})
.then(function(response) {
   deferred.resolve(response)
   log("got data");
 },
 function(error){
   log("failed to get data");
 });`